# Using ExcelApp.Caller from the Excel2000 unit

Tags: delphi, excel

I'm writing an Excel-addin that implements custom Excel functions using XLAutomationAddin.

In the Excel2000 unit you can use the `ExcelApplication.Caller` property to ascertain the ExcelRange that called your custom function.

However the definition of the `Excel2000.pas` typelib says that I need to use

```
property ExcelApplication.Caller[Index: OleVariant; lcid: Integer]: OleVariant;
```

No matter what I try I cannot get this to work because Excel keeps on refusing any parameters that I put in.
I know I can input `0` OR `LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT` into `lcid`, but what does Excel want for the `Index` parameter?

Comment: Index documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff193687.aspx  as for `lcid`, use `LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yep the param is listed as optional, but using `EmptyParam` causes an error, so either the docs are lying, the implementation is broken or something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to cast the ExcelApplication into an OleVariant.

Like so:

```
unit ExcelHelper;
....
implementation

var
  Excel: ExcelApplication;  {global var in unit}

function Caller: ExcelRange;
var
  ExcelAsVar: OleVariant;
begin
  try
    ExcelAsVar:= Excel.Application;
    Result:= IUnkown(ExcelAsVar.Caller) as ExcelRange;
  except 
    Result:= nil;
  end; {try}
end;
```